# C++ Оптимизировать код

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Вот тут есть код

```
 const wchar_t *GetWC(const char *c)
 {
  const size_t cSize = strlen(c)+1;
  wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
  mbstowcs (wc, c, cSize);

  return wc;
}


 void killProcessByName(const char *filename)
 {
    HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
    pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
    BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
    while (hRes)
  {
    if (wcscmp(pEntry.szExeFile, GetWC(filename)) == 0)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                      (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProcess != NULL)
        {
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
    hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
}
CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}


bool findWindow_by_name(const char *name){
PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
char hWnd[18] = {'\0'};

entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
{
    while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        if (wcscmp(entry.szExeFile, GetWC(name)) == 0)
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }
}

CloseHandle(snapshot);

return false;
}



int loop = true;

 void killAll(char* process[], int count){
  for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
     killProcessByName(process[i]);
  }
 }

  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
  {
     ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

      if(argc != 1){
       while(loop){
          for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
           if(!findWindow_by_name(argv[i])){
            killAll(argv, argc);
               loop = false;
           }
       }
     }
  }

    return 0;
  }
```

Ну и вот, он должен искать процессы которые я задам, и он их ищет, если этих процессов нет, то он убирает еще другие.
По сути все работает, но ОЗУ без остановки растет, да и ЦП, стоит около 50%.
Кто поможет оптимизировать код, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Если все работает, может оставить как есть?

Comment: Но набрать за минуту 100 мб ОЗУ, не есть хорошо!
И при том, что он продолжает расти

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция `const wchar_t *GetWC(const char *c)` каждый раз выделяет память в куче оператором `new` в строке:

```
wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
```

Далее нигде в программе вы её не освобождаете, соответственно потребление только растет.

Comment: где именно нужно его освобождать?

Comment: @HackMemory там два места где GetWC используется. В каждом надо дописать `delete`, примерно так: http://pastebin.com/t60hU8h3

Comment: все разобрался
а что делать с цп? Хоть не так критично, но все же 50 цп, тоже не мало

Comment: @HackMemory добавить в циклы `Sleep(100)`. Наверное достаточно в цикл, который в `main` (не знаю точно какая логика у приложения).

Comment: Да, спасибо! Помогло.